# Previewing raster catalogs raster field in Windows form?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

**What I want to achieve:** 
The attribute table for an ArcGIS Raster Catalog contains a raster field.  When a raster field cell is clicked with the mouse, a preview window displaying the raster associated with the row is displayed.  I want to achieve the same or equivalent functionality, but within a windows form.

**What I've tried:** 
I have managed to display the full attribute table of a RasterCatalog layer within a .Net DataGrid using this code 
['Bind a geodatabase table to a .NET control'](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000312000000).   However, whilst the raster column is populated with text 'raster', it is not possible to get a preview of the raster.

One solution could be to add the image for each row to the datagrid as detailed [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-image.htm), but I'd prefer if I could keep the Esri raster field functionality if possible.